# Install Tails with persistent storage on VirtualBox

Tags: boot, virtualbox, disk-image, tails-os

Tails OS is distributed either via .iso or .img file. The only .img can have persistent storage, but only .iso can be mounted to VirtualBox and properly booted. I would like to have VirtualBox Tails machine with persistent storage and ability to install 3rd parties software.

Below is what I did. In couple of words I decided to use flash drive emulator. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.

I built `dummy_hcd.ko` for my kernel and got flash drive via

```
$ sudo modprobe dummy_hcd
$ fallocate -l 8GiB /path/to/flash-drive-file
$ sudo modprobe g_mass_storage file=/path/to/flash-drive-file idVendor=0x1d6b idProduct=0x0104 iManufacturer=Myself iProduct=VirtualBlockDevice iSerialNumber=123
```

Then I expand [Tails OS .img file](https://ftp.fau.de/tails/stable/tails-amd64-3.13.2/tails-amd64-3.13.2.img) to that drive by using `dd` as to usual USB flash drive via issuing following (`/dev/sdd` is my virtual flash drive)

```
$ dd if=tails-amd64-3.13.2.img of=/dev/sdd bs=16M
```

After that I got `/dev/sdd1` partition that I can mount and see the image content. It's size is exactly equal to `tails-amd64-3.13.2.img` file size.

Then I created .vmdk VirtualBox file tied to `/dev/sdd` via

```
$ sudo VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename  ~/usb.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sdd
```

I created new virtual machine and selected this .vmdk file, and started it. Unfortunately, while booting it complaints to insufficient disk space and stop booting. I took `gparted` and resized this partition. `gparted` shows me a message where suggests to fix GPT table I accepted it. The same  `parted` does.

```
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/sdd appears to be used, you can
fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 14364672 blocks) or continue with
the current setting? 
Fix/Ignore? Fix                                                           
Model: Linux File-Stor Gadget (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 8590MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name   Flags
 1      1049kB  1235MB  1234MB  fat32        Tails  boot, hidden, legacy_boot, esp
```

And after that (it's only enough to apply GPT fix and not actually use unallocated space) I, unfortunately, get this message from kernel. I suppose that it can't find the root file system to mount and continue booting `init` process from this file system maybe.

[image]

But the shell is available and rootfs is mounted to ramdisk and can be listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following has been successfully tested with **VirtualBox 6.1.32** and **Tails 5.1**.

#### Step 1: Prepare disk image

1. Download the [**USB image** of Tails from the project's website](https://tails.boum.org/install/download/index.en.html)
2. Convert the downloaded image to VDI format:

   `$ VBoxManage convertfromraw Tails-amd64-5.1.img Tails.vdi --format vdi`

   (NOTE: the .img file is no longer required after this and may be deleted)
3. Resize the VDI to make room for the persistent volume:

   `$ VBoxManage modifyhd Tails.vdi --resize 16384`

   (NOTE: use 8000 MB + <desired-size-of-persistent-volume-in-MB> as resize value)

#### Step 2: Set up virtual machine

1. Follow the [instructions provided on the project's website](https://tails.boum.org/doc/advanced_topics/virtualization/virtualbox/index.en.html) to set up a new VM for Tails
2. Change the following settings of the newly created VM:

   - *System* -> *Motherboard* -> *Extended Features* -> ☑ *Enable EFI (special OSes only)*

     (NOTE: required to be able to boot from USB storage)
   - *Storage* -> *Add new storage controller* (leftmost icon at the bottom) -> *USB*
   - *Storage* -> *Controller: USB* -> *Add new storage attachment* (third icon from the left at the bottom) -> *Hard Disk* -> Select VDI image created in Step 1
3. Set VM resolution (optional):

   `$ VBoxManage setextradata <vm-name> VBoxInternal2/EfiGraphicsResolution <resolution>`

   (NOTE: supply `<resolution>` in format 'WIDTHxHEIGHT', e.g. '1600x900')

#### Step 3: Boot virtual machine, set up persistent volume

1. Start the virtual machine
2. From the boot menu, select **Tails (External Hard Disk)**

   (NOTE: refer to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/705387/399674) on how to permanently modify the boot menu if desired)
3. Once Tails has booted up, select *Applications* -> *Tails* -> *Configure persistent volume* to set up the persistent volume

#### Screenshots:

[image: Enable EFI for USB boot]

[image: Add USB storage / image]

[image: Select correct boot menu entry]

[image: Set up persistent volume]

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the disk you created is not attached to VirtualBox as a removable USB drive, which is what Tails (or, more precisely, the `live-boot` tool that is used by Tails) is looking for. As far as I know, it's not supported by VirtualBox to add a disk as a removable USB drive.

But since you're on Ubuntu, you can use `virt-manager` instead of VirtualBox to use a persistent volume in a VM: https://tails.boum.org/doc/advanced_topics/virtualization/virt-manager/index.en.html#usb_image

Answer (score 2):

Not enough "reputation" to vote or comment on @Maxxim's answer, this is an addition (feel free to pls. integrate into your answer, Maxxim):

After taking Maxxims approach one has to manually select 3rd boot option every.single.boot. IMO better is to edit grub.cfg from a rootshell:

```
mount -o remount -w /lib/live/mount/medium/
find /lib/live/mount/medium/EFI/debian/ -name "grub*.cfg" | xargs sed -i 's/ live-media=removable//g'
mount -o remount -r /lib/live/mount/medium/
```

Afterwards Tails starts w/o interaction.

Comment: I added a link to your answer to mine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you "cannot"(*) run Virtualbox and virt-manager simultaneously, as they will compete for the control of the hardware (I would love to be wrong on this one...). This is a showstopper if one has many VirtualBox VMs already and only want to run Tails in addition. Need to either be possible to run both, or to find a way to do this on Virtualbox. The alternative as it stands now (moving everything to virt-manager), is a much bigger question - a rather tall order.

(*)Ref. https://askubuntu.com/questions/413511/can-virtualbox-and-kvm-run-alongside-each-other

There is a tool that "sometimes" works around this limitation in Virtualbox ("cannot add a disk as a removable USB drive"); **Plop Boot Manager**, ref.:
- https://www.howtogeek.com/97923/how-to-boot-a-vmware-virtual-machine-from-a-usb-drive/
- https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanagers.html